# Put ending and starting text from the selected text spanning over multiple divs in javascript

Tags: javascript, range, selectedtext

I am trying to put text before and after selected text spanning over multiple divs.For example if the text is

```
  <p>This is a random text<p>
  <p>Another random text<p>
```

Now if the user selects "is a random text Another random text" from the two p tags.The output should be

```
  <p>This hello world is a random text hello world<p>
  <p>hello world Another random text hello world<p>
```

I know how to put text before and after the selected text but how do i insert text before each p ending and after the start of another selected p tag.

```
function surroundSelection(textBefore, textAfter) {
if (window.getSelection) {       
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var startNode = range.startContainer, startOffset = range.startOffset;
        var boundaryRange = range.cloneRange();
        var startTextNode = document.createTextNode(textBefore);
        var endTextNode = document.createTextNode(textAfter);
        boundaryRange.collapse(false);
        boundaryRange.insertNode(endTextNode);
        boundaryRange.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
        boundaryRange.collapse(true);
        boundaryRange.insertNode(startTextNode);

        // Reselect the original text
        range.setStartBefore(startTextNode);

        range.setEndAfter(endTextNode);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

This just adds the text before and after the selected text irrespective of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Range.extractContents` to remove the selection and add it to a DocumentFragment. Then you can loop over the `children`, change the `textContent` and use `Range.insertNode` to add them back to the parent element.

Here is an example.

Had to clean up the parent element from left over empty `p` elements after extracting the content, did not figure out how to do that without an extra clean up function. Seems like `extractContents` only extracts the text node and leaves the empty element in the DOM, but i might be wrong.

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

function cleanUpEmptyElem (collection, parent) {
  collection.forEach(function(elem) {
    if(elem.textContent.length < 1) {
      parent.removeChild(elem);
    }
  })
}

function surroundSelection (selection) {
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  if (range.commonAncestorContainer.nodeType !== 3) {
    [].slice.call(range.extractContents().children).forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.textContent = "Foo " + elem.textContent + " Bar";
      range.insertNode(elem);
    });
    cleanUpEmptyElem([].slice.call(range.commonAncestorContainer.children), range.commonAncestorContainer)
  } else {
    range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement.textContent = "Foo " + range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement.textContent + " Bar";
  }
  range.detach();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
}


btn[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().rangeCount) {
    surroundSelection(window.getSelection());
  } else {
    console.log("either nothing is selected or window.getSelection is not available")
  }
}, false)
```

```css
button {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is a random text</p>
  <p>Another random text</p>
  <p>More random text</p>
  <p>Another random text</p>
</div>

<button>insert text in selected elements</button>
```